# In Python 3.9, why does ```find_spec``` doesn't find my relative import?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to check the existence of a package before loading it.

I have the following code `test.py`:

```
from importlib.util import find_spec
print(f".libs imports {find_spec('wolfpy','.libs')}")

from .libs import wolfpy
```

The print says ".libs imports None" but the second import works fine. I was expecting the print to give something else than None. Note that `wolfpy` is a `*.pyd` file. So in my directory I have:

```
./test.py
./libs/wolfpy.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
```

How should I call `find_spec` so that it gives me the spec of my import ?

Comment: I don't think the package argument to `find_spec` is allowed to be relative (I *think* it's supposed to be an anchoring absolute package name, that allows the `name` argument to be relative to it). I can't swear to this though; the docs are not very clear on it.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the first comment, I re-read the documentation. Although not entirely satisfying, here's my answer:

```
from importlib.util import find_spec
print(f".libs imports {find_spec('wolfhece.libs.wolfpy')}")
```

Here I give the full path to the package, starting at the *root* of my python project. In that case, `find_spec` finds my local package first (before looking in the site package). But this works only because my package's full name corresponds to the directory structure of my project and that the root comes first on the `sys.path`.

Comment: All (save very weird import hooking packages) packages correspond to a directory structure rooted in a directory in `sys.path`, so saying "this works only because my package's full name corresponds to the directory structure of my project and that the root comes first on the `sys.path`" is like saying "this only works because I wrote a normal package". Note that if this is in the same package hierarchy as the file that's importing it, you might be able to use `__package__` in the importing file to avoid hard-coding too much of the package name(s).